# Why doesn't my textbox show an updated value every second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that uses jQuery 1.8.0. It's supposed to increment the value in the textbox every second, but nothing happens when I run it.

It's been a long time since I've written any JavaScript (I'm used to C++) so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Is jQuery conflicting with the `setInterval` function somehow? Can I not use the `#timer` selector inside a timer?

```js
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(1000, function() {
        i++;
        $('#timer').val(i);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" id="timer" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have the arguments to `setInterval` reversed.

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        i++;
        $('#timer').val(i);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Second, you’re relying on `setInterval` to provide a reliable count. You should use a monotonic clock; `performance.now()` provides this in modern browsers. Solutions based on `Date.now()` or `new Date()` are liable to cause undesired behaviour when the system clock is adjusted.

```
$(function () {
    var start = performance.now();

    setInterval(function () {
        var elapsed = (performance.now() - start) / 1000;
        $('#timer').val(Math.floor(elapsed));
    }, 1000);
});
```

Third, the `type` for textbox `<input>`s is `text`, not `textbox`.

```
<input type="text" id="timer" />
```

Fourth, you’re using an editable textbox to display a changing value without using it as any sort of input. This isn’t friendly to the user; try a `<span>` instead, styling as necessary. You may want to pause the count if the number should ever need to be selected.

```
$(function () {
    var start = performance.now();

    setInterval(function () {
        var elapsed = (performance.now() - start) / 1000;
        $('#timer').text(Math.floor(elapsed));
    }, 1000);
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Fifth, you’re using an outdated version of jQuery. Since you’re using `performance.now()`, jQuery 2.1.x would be correct, but sixth, no jQuery at all would be even better.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var start = performance.now();

    setInterval(function () {
        var elapsed = (performance.now() - start) / 1000;
        document.getElementById('timer').textContent = Math.floor(elapsed);
    }, 1000);
});
```

You may now remove the `<script>` element that includes jQuery. This now reveals an inefficiency that was less obvious with jQuery; you’re querying for the timer element every second. So seventh: keep track of it elsewhere.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
    var start = performance.now();

    setInterval(function () {
        var elapsed = (performance.now() - start) / 1000;
        timer.textContent = Math.floor(elapsed);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Eighth, move your `<script>` block beneath the element and you won’t have to waste time waiting for `DOMContentLoaded` or typing its event listener. Remember to be in strict mode, too.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
    var start = performance.now();

    setInterval(function () {
        var elapsed = (performance.now() - start) / 1000;
        timer.textContent = Math.floor(elapsed);
    }, 1000);
})();
```

```
<span id="timer"></span>

<script src="timer.js" async></script>
```

It’s decent now.

Comment: I don't need the textbox to have an accurate representation of number of seconds elapsed, just an incrementing count (the real code does something slightly different; I just wanted to post a minimal testcase). This is very interesting, though!

Answer (score 4):

Your arguments to `setInterval` are reversed. Do this instead:

```
setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    $('#timer').val(i);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer above note that setInterval will not necessarily stay in sync with the actual time. ie after 60 repetitions considerably more (or less) than 60 seconds may have actually passed.

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the arguments in setInterval.

> setInterval( function() {
>      i++;
>      $('#timer').val(i);
>   }, 1000);